# Safe remove of grub and lilo instead?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

lenovoZ570, i7 x64,8GB, 700GB, Nvidia Optimus+intel, 1366x768, win7+11.10 ubuntu+kubuntu. Until now nvidia isn´t installed or used.

Some problems, which may relay one on another or interact:

```
 * two grub2, one inactive on the ubuntu partition and one at MBR really on kubuntu
   partition
 * after running startup to configure grub2 strange things happen during boot or at
   shutdown
 * 14 entries in grub, 6 ubuntu(30012,30014,30015) 4kubuntu(30014,30015) 2win7 and 2
   memtest
```

At PC-paper COM was written, it is best to run win boot manager, as long as there is win on the machine. But i work more with linux and remember "lilo" from suse doing a nicely job.
**Is it possible to remove this boring grub2 safely and install lilo, despite it is from a rival business?**

Answer (score 1):

LILO is not from any business.  It is open source and the original non dos based Linux boot loader ( yes, originally you could load linux from DOS ).  It is still in the repositories if you want to install it, but at this point, using it is like using windows 3.1.  It is ancient and woefully inferior to grub2.

Comment: thanks, but as i remember,there is also some like lilo2. The question is, will it work smoothly together with ubuntu. I need only a loader, which shows my active 8 entries in the order i want. All other staff of grub2 didn´t work for my experience, offen only a prompt without help or more often black blank screens.

Comment: While it is more primitive than Grub, sometimes that works out as a plus. I certainly would not describe it as "woefully inferior". On one of my machines with multiple distributions `Grub2` is so messed up it is unusable except for a single distribution and I wasted 2 days trying to fix it. `LILO` on the other hand works beautifully and allows me to access all of the distributions on that disk.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Grub` install works then I would not deliberately mess with it or with bootloaders in general unless you *have to!* If you do have issues with how `Grub` works on your system then `LILO` is still a very good option. It is more primitive than `Grub` and `Grub2` but that often is a big plus. Note however that if you do end up with a corrupted `LILO` boot loader that it does not give you a command line option, unlike `Grub` and therefore you do then have to boot from a USB, CDROM or external drive and fix it manually.

While they are not specific to Ubuntu, if you need more information these are useful sources:

http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2008/01/22/lilo-and-grub-boot-loaders-made-simple.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LILO